# react context provider throw an error in the rendering method

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context, react-state-management

I am experimenting with react context API, and this is the code I am working on:

```
import * as React from 'react';

interface ProviderState {
  themeColor: string;
}

interface UpdateStateArg {
  key: keyof ProviderState;
  value: string;
}

interface ProviderStore {
  state: ProviderState;
  update: (arg: UpdateStateArg) => void;
}

const Context = React.createContext({} as ProviderStore);

class Provider extends React.Component<{}, ProviderState> {
  readonly state = {
    themeColor: 'red'
  };

  private update = ({ key, value }: UpdateStateArg) => {
    this.setState({ [key]: value });
  }

  render() {
    const store: ProviderStore = {
      state: this.state,
      update: this.update
    };

    return (
      <Context.Provider value={store}>
         {this.props.children}
      </Context.Provider>
    );
  }
}

export { Provider };
```

the ‘Provider’ in rendering method throw following error:

### [image]

`"JSX element type 'ReactElement<any> | null' is not a constructor function for JSX elements.Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'ElementClass"`

In react declaration file 'Provider' has been declared and I think it has been declared correctly, or I may be wrong!

I am using the following versions:

```
react: "^16.5.0"
react-dom: "^16.5.0"
@types/react: "^16.4.7"
@types/react-dom: "^16.0.7"
```

Comment: I've tried to reproduce your issue with the same code and dependency versions (both for loose matching ^ and exact version pinning) and didn't run into the issue. There are 2 things I'd try.
1. Remove your node-modules and package.lock/yarn.lock files and do a clean yarn / npm install

2. Update your typescript version (I was running 3.0.3 when checking)

Comment: thank you for the suggestions, unfortunatly it didn't work, for now, I am using @ts-ignore to bypass the problem.

Comment: This can happen if something has messed up your definition of `JSX.Element`.  For example, I can imagine that certain configurations with several conflicting React type declarations might cause this.  If you add `type Test = JSX.Element` to your file and search for references to `JSX.Element`, do you get a single definition or several?

Comment: ahh, you are right, indeed I did have `JSX.Element` declared somewhere else. now all back to normal. thank you very much.